# Defined variables losing value after using drupal_bootstrap

Tags: 6

We're trying to use drupal_bootstrap to be able to delete a drupal user when a user is inactivated in our internal (non-Drupal) system. It appears that all defined variables set prior to the bootstrap call are losing value as soon as the call is made. Here's the weird part: it only happens on our live server - everything runs perfectly on dev.

Here's the code; I've stuck a whole bunch of error_log statements in so I can see exactly where the variables are disappearing.

```
//email address is empty; delete institute record - but not if it's user 0 or 1
if($institute_uid > 1) {
  error_log("institute uid right before bootstrapping drupal: $institute_uid"); 
  //previous line prints and the $institute_uid is correct

  //set the working directory to your Drupal root - necessary for delete user function
  chdir('/home/www/institute');

  //require the bootstrap include
  require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';

  //Load Drupal
  drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL); 
  //(loads everything, but doesn't render anything)

  error_log("institute uid immediately after bootstrap = $institute_uid"); 
  //previous line prints but the $institute_uid value is blank

  $test = "123";
  error_log("test = $test");
  //previous line prints and $test value is correct

  user_delete(array(), $institute_uid); //$vuid = institute_uid from new_people
  $body .= '<br />Institute account deleted';

}
```

Any ideas? We're new to the bootstrap stuff; maybe there's a server setting, or line in a .ini file somewhere in Drupal that needs to change on our live server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When "register_globals" is enabled, [Drupal unsets all global variables before boostrap](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_unset_globals/6).

Disable the "register_globals" option in your live server.

Comment: That's correct. Another solution, if you don't want do disable register_globals (e.g. used in your old PHP3 site) is to use $_REQUEST['institute_uid'] instead of $institute_uid.